# How can I replace type of object in api platform?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have a project with a custom doctrine type for URL. It returns an `App\Util\Url` object for each URL string in each entity. I also have a normalizer/denormalizer for it, so I get used to transfer it as string in old API.

Now I would like to use API platform. It creates a OpenAPI description for `Url` like

```
Url.jsonld{
    @context {...}
    @id    [...]
    @type  [...]
    schema [...]
    domain [...]
    path   [...]
}
```

I still see a string in the API platform response. It means that normalizer works fine, but OpenAPI still shows my field not as a string, but as an object.

```
{
  "@context": "/api/contexts/Company",
  "@id": "/api/companies",
  "@type": "hydra:Collection",
  "hydra:member": [
    {
      "@id": "/api/companies/1",
      "@type": "Company",
      "name": "company name",
      "description": "company description",
      "id": 1,
      "url": "http://test.com"
    }
  ],
  "hydra:totalItems": 1
}
```

I can use a special param to replace default OpenAPI annotation

```
#[ApiProperty(openapiContext: [])]
```

Unfortunately, there is a lot of `Url` fields and don't want to create `openapiContext` for each. Is there a way to explain API platform that all `Url` objects should be processed as strings as it happens with `DateTime` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best workaround I found is to decorate `api_platform.metadata.property.metadata_factory`.

Create decorator like

```php
namespace App\ApiPlatform;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Property\Factory\PropertyMetadataFactoryInterface;
use App\Util\Url;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\Type;

class PropertyMetadataFactoryDecorator implements PropertyMetadataFactoryInterface
{
    private readonly PropertyMetadataFactoryInterface $decorated;

    public function __construct(PropertyMetadataFactoryInterface $decorated)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function create(string $resourceClass, string $property, array $options = []): ApiProperty
    {
        $result = $this->decorated->create($resourceClass, $property, $options);
        if ($this->isUrlObject($result)) {
            $result = $result->withOpenapiContext(
                [
                    'type' => 'string',
                    'example' => 'en',
                ]
            );
        }

        return $result;
    }

    private function isUrlObject(ApiProperty $property): bool
    {
        $res = false;
        foreach ($property->getBuiltinTypes() as $type) {
            if ($type->getClassName() === Url::class) {
                $res = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return $res;
    }
}
```

Add decorator to `config/services.yaml`

```yaml
App\ApiPlatform\PropertyMetadataFactoryDecorator:
    decorates: 'api_platform.metadata.property.metadata_factory'
    arguments: ['@.inner']
    decoration_priority: -100
```

Not sure how will it affects other parts of the app, but for now works fine.